# Stop one 'type' of listener on a node - firebase / javascript

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a problem while detaching a listener to a node in firebase. I am currently building the chat interface of the app, so you can imagine what I am talking about here.

1. So to listen to the chat and actually display all the messages I use:
   `firebase.database().ref('/path/to/relevant/chatNode').on('value')`

I also have another view in the app that lists all current active chats and it displays the name of the person you are chatting with and underneath you see the last message that is available in the chat.

2. To keep that last part in sync with the DB I use:
   `firebase.database().ref('/path/to/relevant/chatNode').limitToLast(1).on('child_added')`

Now the issue is that I want to stop listening to changes once the users exits from the view that displays all the messages. Basically I want to call `.off()` on listener **number 1**, but NOT on **number 2**.

However, I just realized that `.off()` stops both listeners. Is there a way to specify which type of listener I want to stop syncing or do I need to recall listener **number 2** once the user navigates away from the actual chat?

In the firebase docs you can find this line:
`You can remove a single listener by passing it as a parameter to off().`

How do you pass a single listener as a parameter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you register a listener with `on()` it will return the function. You can pass that into `off` to stop only that listener.

So:

```
var listener = firebase.database().ref('/path/to/relevant/chatNode').on('value')
```

And then:

```
firebase.database().ref('/path/to/relevant/chatNode').off('value', listener)
```